# Disable Google Calendar warning about external guests

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

I use Google Apps for personal use and of course Google Calendar. I love to invite people using Google Calendar to meetings and they have a nice link to say "YES!" and so on.

But Google Calendar always warns me, that I try to invite people who are NOT in my organization. Because I am alone in my Google Apps organisation, I assume that happens a lot more in the future.

How can I disable this security question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enable/disable external invitation prompts, you must have an Administrator account. This will open the Google Admin console.

From the dashboard, go to Apps > Google Apps > Calendar > Sharing Settings > External invitations.

Choose ON or OFF for the setting.

Comment: Thanks for this. A thousand thank-yous.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [these](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/calendar/ndec8BgyUDQ/23_k0fp_QVEJ) [two](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/t_AqVBTW_NE) feature requests suggest that you can't.